# Why SQL query returns values that should be filtered out by condition in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I am not able to understand the output of my SQL queries and trying to get some sense of it. My data set is as follows

```
table name: my_table

assignee
--------
Mat_Bar
dan.eml
mon.gal
```

My first simple query

```
WITH rows as
(
  SELECT 
  distinct(assignee) 
  FROM 
  my_table
  WHERE 
  assignee NOT LIKE '%_%'
)
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE assignee = 'Mat_Bar'
```

Above query returned zero records as expected

Now I am adding another OR condition to above query as follows

```
WITH rows as
(
  SELECT 
  distinct(assignee) 
  FROM 
  my_table
  WHERE 
  assignee NOT LIKE '%_%' OR assignee NOT LIKE '%.%'
)
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE assignee = 'Mat_Bar'
```

Above query returns one row "Mat_Bar"

I am expecting my second query should return zero records too as the first one but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

PS: I am running the query on AWS Athena (Presto)

Thanks

Comment: Distinct is not a function, it's a part of `select distinct`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Remove those extra parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. simply `SELECT  DISTINCT assignee FROM...`.

Comment: What do you want to be returned? The `_` is a wildcard (for one character.)

Comment: Use `AND` instead of `OR`?

Answer (score 1):

This does not do what you think:

```
assignee NOT LIKE '%_%'
```

Because `_` is a wildcard that matches one character, this just checks that `assignee` is not a single character.

I suspect that you are confusing `LIKE` with [`regexp_like()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like).  `LIKE` is much more limited and only supports two wildcards:  `%` and `_`.

Comment: Thanks. I am indeed confused with what LIKE can do. Found the documentation which could help https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Negated conditions need to be `AND`ed together, not `OR`ed, otherwise the result will always be true. Consider

```
a != 0 OR a != 1
```

Regardless of the value of `a`, including 0 and 1, the condition will always be true. So change your condition to

```
assignee NOT LIKE '%\_%' AND assignee NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Note that `_` is a wildcard matching a single character so to match a literal `_` you need to escape it as I have done above.